# service worker caching vs VuexPersistence

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, service-worker

I guess it's a silly question as I could not find the topic anywhere, but I am currently learning about service workers and caching features, and was wondering if VuexPersistence was still needed if you implement all your caching strategy with sw? Are they comparable, what make them different? And when should I use one instead of the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### VuexPersistence:

stores the data in your Vuex-Store, inside your Browsers localStorage and makes it reusable.
Example: you have a JWToken stored in your Store, wich is then also stored in your localStorage.

---

#### ServiceWorker:

is caching the HTML at your side.
It means it allows the browser a faster representing of the website like it would usually.
Normally on visiting a SPA you download the whole stuff at the beginning and only fetch data.
If you close the browser now, the "SPA" is lost and need to be redownloaded on next visit of the SPA.

ServiceWorker is caching this very SPA inside your Browser and allows a faster Clientside performance.

Comment: thanks very much! so the cache with sw is only about the html and assets like images, etc. correct? I thought you could also add requests (like for example a get request to have all the user's football games he made in a year) in your cache so that you get the response quicker on next call. If it's only html that can be cached then I understand now. But if it's any kind of request (let's say to get the user's jwtoken) then I feel you could use either sw or vuex

Comment: @Nassim exactly. But caching data like users football games shouldn't be saved in the localStorage.
The reason ist simple, 1min after you fetched user data, the data is no more "up to date". it could be done a million changes in that 1min that would make your data srsly "old". thats why you can stick to Vuex Caching system for stuff like that. this will only cached in the sessionStorage. one more... imagine you cache a list of all Amazon Users in a LocalStorage with PWA (LocalStorage) Caching, do you want the user have millions of GB in his browser saved? :D